# Suppress GCC warnings when storing function pointers

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

I am writing a cross-platform OpenGL function loading library. On Windows, the compiler (oddly enough, both VS *and* GCC) seems fine with implicitly converting one kind of function pointer (the return type from `wglGetProcAddress` being a `void(*)()`) into another type of function pointer.

GCC on *Linux* however is not. `glXGetProcAddress` will return a `void(*)()`, but it will always issue a warning about it. And since OpenGL has literally thousands of these things, it adds up to a giant diagnostic spew that's entirely irrelevant.

Is there some way to disable this particular warning? Either with a `#pragma` or some way of rearranging the code so GCC shuts up? I tried the whole `#pragma diagnostic ignore -Wblahblah`, but I couldn't find a "blahblah" that matched the warning I was getting.

Comment: As a side note, you may want to check out  http://glew.sourceforge.net/ to deal with loading all of those

Comment: @hexist: Yeah, I'm trying to [*replace* GLEW](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home), not use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're supposed to use the provided macros to get the correct types out. For example, taken from the [gl3w](https://github.com/skaslev/gl3w) OpenGL extension loader (you have to run the python script to get it to generate code like this), it has lines that look like:

```
gl3wBindImageTexture = (PFNGLBINDIMAGETEXTUREPROC)get_proc("glBindImageTexture");
```

That weird `PFNGLBINDIMAGETEXTUREPROC` in the middle is a macro for the correct function type of the `glBindImageTexture` function (you can see its name is actually `P`ointer `F`unctio`N` `GLBINDIMAGETEXTURE` `PROC`).

Comment: I'm not a C programmer by trade, but I was told by C programmers that doing unnecessary explicit casts was *bad* in C. That you should let the implicit cast system handle it.

Comment: @Nicol: I'm not sure where you learned that.  In C, you should generally avoid explicitly casting `void*` to other pointer types (such as the return value of `malloc`), since there is an implicit cast from `void*` to any other data pointer type.  However, *function* pointers are entirely different beasts -- there is no implicit function pointer casting, so you should explicitly cast when you need to (which shouldn't be too often, but this looks like a good case here).